# multiline regex python, convert to dict

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I have some output of a command that looks something like this.

```
make:   Toyota
model:  Camry
year:   2020
```

I want to convert this to a dict that looks like this: `{'make': 'Toyota', 'model': 'Camry', 'year': '2020'}`

I can convert one line at a time using some logic like `make:\s*(?P<make>\w+{3-10})` and similarly for `model` and `year`, but how do I come up with a single regex and what do I need to with that regex to extract the info I need?

Answer (score 1):

One way using `yaml`:

```
import yaml

new_str = """make:   Toyota
model:  Camry
year:   2020"""

yaml.safe_load(new_str)
```

Output:

```
{'make': 'Toyota', 'model': 'Camry', 'year': 2020}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `finditer` with a *simple* regex that capture key and value in 2 separate groups, like this:

```
>>> import re
>>> d = {}
>>> for m in re.finditer(r"(\w+):\s*(\S+)", s): d[m.group(1)] = m.group(2)
>>> ...
>>> print (d)
{'make': 'Toyota', 'model': 'Camry', 'year': '2020'}
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `(\w+)`: Match 1+ word characters in capture group #1
- `:\s*`: Match a `:` followed by 0 or more whitespaces
- `(\S+)`: Match 1+ non-whitespace characters in capture group #2

Answer (score 0):

Here's a non-iterative approach using a single regsub + string constructs:

```
In [1]: foo = """
   ...: make:   Toyota
   ...: model:  Camry
   ...: year:   2020
   ...: """

In [2]: import re

In [3]: import json

In [4]: json.loads("{" + re.sub(r'(\w+)\s*:\s*(\w+)(\n)', r'"\1": "\2", ', foo, re.MULTILINE).rstrip(", ").lstrip("\n") + "}")
Out[4]: {u'make': u'Toyota', u'model': u'Camry', u'year': u'2020'}

In [5]: bar = json.loads("{" + re.sub(r'(\w+)\s*:\s*(\w+)(\n)', r'"\1": "\2", ', foo, re.MULTILINE).rstrip(", ").lstrip("\n") + "}")

In [6]: print(bar)
{u'make': u'Toyota', u'model': u'Camry', u'year': u'2020'}

In [7]: type(bar)
Out[7]: dict

In [8]:
```